# Similarity of a complex matrix with a triangular matrix with small elements besides the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix with complex coefficients and let $r>0$. I know that there exist a nonsingular matrix $C$ and an upper triangular matrix $T$ such that $A=C^{-1}TC$.
I wish to prove the existence of nonsingular $C$ and upper triangular $T$ such that that equality holds and aditional all elements $t_{ij}$ of $T$ over the main diagonal satisfy  $|t_{ij}|<r$.

Thanks

Comment: If $A = r I$ the result is false. Is some condition missing?

Comment: @Gribouillis he says "over" the main diagonal.

Comment: @ancientmathematician sorry, my english is far from perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma: Let $N$ be a $k\times k$ matrix with $1$'s on the superdiagonal and $0$ elsewhere. The $N$ and $\epsilon N$ are similar for any $\epsilon\not=0$.

Proof: By looking at the ranks of $(\epsilon N)^s$  we see that the Jordan form of $\epsilon N$ is $N$.

Now $A$ is similar to its Jordan Form, and we can apply the lemma to $J_{p}(\lambda)-\lambda$ for each Jordan block.